# How to change the Assembly Name in C# Programmatically

Tags: c#, assemblies

I want to change the name of my Assembly Programmatically in C#, there is a way through which I can change it from Project Properties, but I want to change it Programmatically, so that my output .exe name is changed.. Any trick for that?

Comment: do you mean that you want to write a plug-in for visual Studio that will edit the project file to change the output name of the assembly?

Comment: Do you intend to do this at compile time?

Comment: I want it to change at compile time you can say, so that I can change the name of my output exe on the fly..(based on some conditional statement)

Comment: Do you just want to change OutputPath in the project files? Otherwise you're going to run into a lot of issues making changes on the fly, without custom msbuild work that dynamically modifies or creates temporary projects, etc. Debugging could be a pain!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this in the Post-Build Event. These scripts are commandline scripts that get executed after the Build process finished

```
ren "$(TargetFileName)" new-filename.exe
```

#### Edit:

You can configure the Postbuild Event by right-clicking on your Project in Visual Studio and selecting Properties. There you have a Tab called Buildevents. There is one for Prebuild and one for Postbuild. At the bottom you can select under what circumstances the Script should be run. This description assumes you are using Visual Studio 2008. The Events are also available in earlier versions, and the way to reach them should be similar (sorry, can't remember exactly howto).

> Note: if the assembly file name has space then insert `$(TargetFileName)` between two quotation, like this: `"$(TargetFileName)"`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to configure the Post Build Events??

Comment: Changing the filename doesn't change the assembly name.  If I have Foo as my assembly name in project settings, then I rename it to Bar.dll, then open it in reflector, the name will still show as Foo.

Answer (score 0):

In a post-build event, this should do the trick:

```
if <Condition> == <truevalue> xcopy output.dll newassembly.dll /y /s /d
```

To configure post-build events: right-click the project in Solution Explorer, click Properties, then click Build Events.

Comment: Changing the filename doesn't change the assembly name. If I have Foo as my assembly name in project settings, then I rename it to Bar.dll, then open it in reflector, the name will still show as Foo.

Comment: Twice in the question, the OP makes it clear he or she wants to change the name of the .exe file. "name of my Assembly" not "Assembly Name", and "my output .exe name".