# Programmatically changing assembly (application) name?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF project running on Windows 7 Embedded & Windows 8 Pro. In the taskbar when the application is pinned and I right-click the application icon, the C# project name pops up. Is there a way to change this name programmatically?

I want to load the application name from an .ini file at run-time.

**UPDATE:**
I have prior to asking this question searched and reviewed the other question that asks a similar, but different question on how to change the file name after compilation. I do not want to change the file name, just the name on the taskbar after right-clicking the application icon that is pinned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the Assembly Name in C# Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425323/how-to-change-the-assembly-name-in-c-sharp-programmatically)

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question, but I already searched on Google and here. That question specifically deals with changing the file name after compilation and that was also the final solution. Mine deals with just the shortcut on the taskbar after right clicking the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is no "easy" way to do it, necessarily.

I would assume you have to run some sort of script or use Powershell.

1. Using method ?, create or rename a shortcut to your `.exe` with the name you want to show up in the pinned application.
2. Start the application using the shortcut. (At this point the "application name" in the task bar is the name of the shortcut used to launch your .exe)
3. Pin the application.
4. Shortcut is added to AppData, and the application will remain the same name of the shortcut.

Here was my pinned task bar info: `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`

You could also probably modify the registry and add the shortcut straight to the folder listed above, then reload `explorer.exe`, but you have to worry about user permissions and what not.  Either way, this should give you something to roll with.